# Sklearn: adding lemmatizer to CountVectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lemmatization, countvectorizer

I added lemmatization to my countvectorizer, as explained on this [Sklearn page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html).

```
from nltk import word_tokenize          
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
class LemmaTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    def __call__(self, articles):
        return [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in word_tokenize(articles)]

tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer,
                       strip_accents = 'unicode',
                       stop_words = 'english',
                       lowercase = True,
                       token_pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b', # keeps words of 3 or more characters
                       max_df = 0.5,
                       min_df = 10)
```

However, when creating a *dtm* using `fit_transform`, I get the error below (of which I can't make sense). Before adding the lemmatization to my vectorizer, the dtm code always worked. I went deeper into the manual, and tried some things with the code, but couldn't find any solution.

```
dtm_tf = tf_vectorizer.fit_transform(articles)
```

**Update:**

After following @MaxU's advice below, the code run without error, however numbers and punctuation were not ommited from my output. I run individual tests to see which of the other functions after `LemmaTokenizer()` do and do not work. Here is the result:

```
strip_accents = 'unicode', # works
stop_words = 'english', # works
lowercase = True, # works
token_pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b', # does not work
max_df = 0.5, # works
min_df = 10 # works
```

Appearantly, it is just `token_pattern` which became inactive. Here is the updated and working code without `token_pattern` (I just needed to install the 'punkt' and 'wordnet' packages first):

```
from nltk import word_tokenize          
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer 
class LemmaTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    def __call__(self, articles):
        return [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in word_tokenize(articles)]

tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer(),
                                strip_accents = 'unicode', # works 
                                stop_words = 'english', # works
                                lowercase = True, # works
                                max_df = 0.5, # works
                                min_df = 10) # works
```

For those who want to remove digits, punctuation and words of less than 3 characters (but have no idea how), here is one way that does it for me when working from Pandas dataframe

```
# when working from Pandas dataframe

df['TEXT'] = df['TEXT'].str.replace('\d+', '') # for digits
df['TEXT'] = df['TEXT'].str.replace(r'(\b\w{1,2}\b)', '') # for words
df['TEXT'] = df['TEXT'].str.replace('[^\w\s]', '') # for punctuation
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. But, the example from sklearn seems sloppy. A lemmatizer needs a part of speech tag to work correctly. This is usually inferred using the pos_tag nltk function before tokenization.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be:

```
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer(),
# NOTE:                        ---------------------->  ^^
```

instead of:

```
tf_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=LemmaTokenizer,
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, the code runs indeed without error. However, the functions after `LemmaTokenizer()` do not work anymore. Most importantly, `token_pattern = r'\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b'` became inactive (so my topics are full of numbers and punctuation). Is it possible to integrated everything in one step? Or shall I seperate the two? (and remove numbers and punctuation beforehand).

Comment: @Rens, please open a new question and provide there a small (3-5 rows) reproducible sample data set and your code

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the code, it helps me.
Here is an other way to do with inactive `token_pattern` :

```
import re
class LemmaTokenizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
    def __call__(self, doc):
        regex_num_ponctuation = '(\d+)|([^\w\s])'
        regex_little_words = r'(\b\w{1,2}\b)'
        return [self.wnl.lemmatize(t) for t in word_tokenize(doc) 
                if not re.search(regex_num_ponctuation, t) and not re.search(regex_little_words, t)]
```

With Regex into the class LemmaTokenizer.

Comment: That is a nice added option, and of course the preferred way to go! So thanks. Just a side note: for my topic models, I finally stopped using the lemmatizer, as it created less nice results. Also see: https://mimno.infosci.cornell.edu/papers/schofield_tacl_2016.pdf